# Creating a method for multiple field validations

Tags: c#, validation

As question states I am trying to create a way to validate every field on my form. Every field on my  form requires the same validation. I thought about creating a method to call to avoid re-writing code. Also for my method not to fail when it is called multiple times. How can I use the valdiations below to create a method or other type of statement for all my field validations?

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstnameTextBox.Text))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Please enter a first name");
}
else if (!Int32.TryParse(firstnameTextBox.Text, out number))
{
     MessageBox.Show("No numbers allowed for their first name");
}
```

Possible method

```
private bool formValidation(string text)
{
    int number;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a first name");
    }
    else if (!Int32.TryParse(text , out number))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No numbers allowed for their first name");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the _possible method_?

Comment: @TimSchmelter when I tried to use one like it in the past it caused issues.

Comment: What kind of _issues_? Please provide more details. Currently it's difficult to answer such a vague question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter be back with you shortly

Comment: @TimSchmelter that method does work. Last time I tried it, it returned errors so I figured I made my method wrong.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos: you are not returning `false` value when user enters empty string  or invalid integer. so irrespective of the input string your method returns `true` always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:** you are not returning `false` value when user enters empty string or invalid integer. so irrespective of the input string your method returns `true` always.

**Solution 1:** you need to `return false` value when user enters empty string  or invalid integer.

**Suggestion :** `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` method only check wether string is `null` or `empty` but it doesnot check for `whitespaces`, here in your code user can enter whitespaces (user inputs from textboxes) which needs to be identified. so i would suggest you to use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` instead of `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` which will check for Null,Empty and whitespace.

**Complete Code:**

```
private bool formValidation(string text)
{
    int number;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a first name");
        return false;
    }
    else if (!Int32.TryParse(text , out number))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No numbers allowed for their first name");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You are right I didn't think of that.

Comment: How can I wrap all m if statements together? I have six method calls then if those are ok they execute the insert command.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like these, there are two better options so as not to tarnish your code with cross-cutting concerns. I tend to use Attributes that decorate fields / properties or methods in my classes and then have a general inspector read these at runtime.

Another option, similar but probably more robust, is to consider using some Aspect Oriented Programming tool such as PostSharp